# what goes is wrong with my heroku deploy?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, heroku, progressive-web-apps

I have a problem with my deploy. I build a app Localy with Laravel & vueJs this is a Pwa.
So now I have end that everything works fine. My db mysql got 5 migrate, and seeders.

So now I want to deploy to heroku, I do it exactly like that: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel

But I got the famous 500 internal errors so I try to join my db with config var. I do heroku run php migrate working fine the seeding is good no error.
I just can you drop that :

> 2020-04-23T08:01:00.908862+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=quiet-dusk-57631.herokuapp.com request_id=59ac99b0-1dbf-4b38-a2bf-641b8ef8ce33 fwd="92.137.142.110" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1782 protocol=https`
>
> 2020-04-23T08:01:00.902965+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.32.231.221 - - [23/Apr/2020:08:01:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 1558 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/81.0.4044.92 Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36

But 500 internal errors is ir :( I try something like that :

```
Add "postinstall"

"npm run prod" in script (package.json)

run production

npm install ....
```

Everything I found maybe worked, but nothing work.

If someone can help me :( I don't drop log or code because I don't know what is not going good and except the 500 server error on my app I got no error all is solved before.

EDIT :

So now the title and logo load on page top. But I got this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://guarded-caverns-46403.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://guarded-caverns-46403.herokuapp.com/js/app.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

In web.php i just add 'URL::forceScheme('https');' at the end.

And all works good